# How can I find out if I need to call Close() in MySqlConnection when using?

Tags: c#, dispose, using, mysql-connector, database-connection

> using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

The simple connection code with "using":

```
using (IDbConnection sql = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString))
     {
           try
           {
                sql.Open();
                var x = sql.Execute("query...");
           }
            catch (Exception ex)
           {
                 Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
           }
     }
```

"Using" calls Dispose(), but if Dispose() calls Close()?

How can I find out if I need to call Close() in MySqlConnection when using?

Answer (score 2):

Do nothing.

`Dispose` will close connection properly.

From documentation:

> Dispose()   -  Releases all resources used by the MySqlConnection

Form the source code of MySqlConnection.Dispose

```
void IDisposable.Dispose()
{
    if (State == ConnectionState.Open)
        Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can try this, u can put it in a finally clause

```
if (sql.State == ConnectionState.Open)
{
    sql.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample DBConnect class that I am using. With this class, it is really easy to create a database connection anywhere you want. Just create an object of this class.

This is for MySQL database, if you are using sql server just replace MySql with Sql

Here is my DBConnect class

```
using System    ;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;


namespace test
{

    class DBConnect: IDisposable 
    {
        private static String server = "localhost";
        private static String port = "3306";
        private static String database = "testDB";
        private static String username = "root";
        private static String password = "";

        private static String connectionString = "Server=" + server + ";Port=" + port + ";Database=" + database + ";Uid=" + username + ";Password=" + password + ";";
         public MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);



        public DBConnect() //Constructor
        {

            try
            {
                con.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("Database connected");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
                Console.WriteLine("Database Connection Failed");
                throw new Exception();
            }


        }


        public void Dispose()
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is how you use this class

```
using(DBConnect db = new DBConnect())
{
    String q = "your sql Statement here";
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(q, db.con);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("Item added", "Done", MessageBoxButtons.OK,mesageBoxIcon.Information);
                }
```